# OTRS Postmaster Filter: Regex for finding multiline text

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, otrs

I'm using OTRS 3.3. and I'm currently trying to get the following done:
I have to get some multiline text out of an email using PostMaster Filter feature. The email contains the following text (for example):

```
Description: 

Job to be done according to specifikation
AB C12356 
AB C15356 
AB C12357 
AB C12956 
AB C12056

Details:
```

I have to get the text between "Description" until "Details" begins. I tried using the regEx

```
Description:\n\n.*
```

but I only get the first line of the wanted text. I read that I could use "/m" or "/g" but I don't really get how it works or how I can get text until another text begins.

Can someone help me finding the fitting regEx for this?

Comment: You're only reading one line at a time. Have you tried using `File::Slurp` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're currently only reading one line at a time.

You should change the input record separator, which is set to "\n" by default.

```
local undef $/;
```

or

```
use English;
local undef $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;
```

If you undef it, you can read the whole multiline string in one go.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use English;
local undef $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR;

my $record = (<>);

if ($record =~ /.*Description:(.*)Details.*/s){
    print $1;
}
```

The regexp modifier s allows . to match newlines, which it does not by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use File::Slurp;

my $file = read_file('in.txt');

while($file=~/Description:(.*)Details/gs){
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
Job to be done according to specifikation
AB C12356 
AB C15356 
AB C12357 
AB C12956 
AB C12056
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with the Postmaster Filters you can define in the Admin GUI of OTRS; because there your regexes always will match a single line only.

You can achieve your requirements by writing a custom [Ticket Postmaster Module](http://doc.otrs.org/developer/3.3/en/html/otrs-module-layers.html#core-modules) or maybe by using a [CMD Postmaster Filter](http://doc.otrs.org/3.3/en/html/email-settings.html#email-receiving-filter).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/Description:(.+?)Details:/s
```

**Description**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Demo**

http://regex101.com/r/nM2uF1

**Discussion**

I have added the `s` modifier to let `.` match new lines too.

> I could use "/m" or "/g" but I don't really get how it works

- The `/m` (multiline) modifier indicates that the `^` and `$` metachars should match only the beginning and the end of a line.
- The `/g` (global) modifier indicates that the regex flavor doesn't stop at the first match. Instead the flavor will find all matches inside your string.

Comment: Of course, you need to have the entire email in the string you are applying this regex to.